# Masked Text box for IP Address

Tags: asp.net

I want the masked text for the IPAddress in ASP.Net.

and below are the ipaddress which are some possible addresses.

Ex:

```
192.168.30.2

10.1.1.2

31.23.212.2
```

So, number one has 3 numbers, but number 2 has only 2.  Right now, the default MaskedTextBox makes you enter in all three numbers before going to the next octet.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 990.990.990.990 or ###.###.###.### for your [Mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) property

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you would need to write a javascript function yourself. MaskEdit included in asp.net toolkit offers only fixed mask, which means, you would need to have IP address in a format like this:

010.001.001.002

That is, to say at least, ugly. If someone knows of any workaround for this, I'd gladly see it.

So, my solution would be to use the regular expression for IP address and write a JS function, that reacts on user input according to this expression.